# Relative Path issues in Bootstrap 3 Glyphicon styles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

[image: My project folder]

Please refer the image. Everything working fine in both index1.html and index2.html. But Glyphicon are not visible in index2.html, but it works fine in index1.html

Comment: Are you getting 404 errors in console ?

Comment: As Lekhnath says, check console to see if it can find the glyphicon fonts. You'll need to include it from root (i.e. /fonts/glyphicons... rather than ../fonts/glyphicons...) for it to work at different directory levels

Comment: I am not getting 404 errors in console. Just now i noticed that it works in all browsers other than Mozilla Firefox

Answer (score 0):

when referencing "other" files in the root directory from a child try using **../** as this will put you up **1** directory

alternatively use **/** before the file reference and it will assume your starting your file path from root

## example

*../../../myfile.css* - takes you back **UP** three directories

*/tree1/tree2/tree3/myfile.css* - takes you three folders in from the root to find the respective file for reference

your glyphs reference included in index2.html would be

../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 
**OR**
/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf